# How do I make use of Chrome instant search in my own search engine?

Tags: google-chrome, search-engine

Is it possible to make use of the Chrome instant search feature for non-Google searches? If so, does anyone know if there are any docs about to show you how to make use of instant search in your own search engine?

Comment: You can change the search engine Chrome uses in the settings: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95653 Or are you talking about [Google Instant](http://google.com/instant)?

Comment: @Juhana I have my own search engine (meaning an input field on my web page set as default Chrome search engine) and I want to use `Enable Instant for faster searching (omnibox input may be logged)` option in Chrome.

Comment: @MarekSapota See my answer below; did it work out?

Comment: @tehsockz I’m looking at it right, looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Take a look at [this page](http://dev.chromium.org/searchbox) for a how-to on how you can interface with the Omnibox.

See [this](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender) for info about the prerenderer.

Comment: The page you provided took me to OpenSearch specification, which is great — now I can get suggestions from my search engine, but instant still doesn’t work.  Instant is the thing that loads pages even before I complete my query and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

Google has recently updated the Chrome browser.

Now activation / deactivation is available under new setting.

**Steps**

1. Click on Chrome browser "..."
2. Choose settings
3. Go to "Advanced section"
4. Go to "Privacy and Security"
5. Go to "Sync and Google services"
6. Go to "Other Google services"
7. Activate OR Deactivate "Autocomplete searches and URLs"

Hooray, you configured "Instant search" behaviour of Chrome browser

**P.S.** [Screenshot for browser configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb2QY.jpg)